# Are general "let's discuss this proposal" threads allowed on Area 51 Discussion Zone?

Tags: discussion, area-51, close-reasons

A recent proposal on Area 51 has yielded a corresponding question ([About Islam medical science](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32346/161991)) on Area 51 Discussion Zone, with the "question" simply a statement of the proposal's merits and an implied invitation to comment. Normally, such broad "discuss topic X" questions are not allowed on the network, but I know that the new site proposal sites are a little oddball in more than one way.

Are such questions allowed, or should they be closed?

Comment: This kind of question is pointless. The basic reason for the proposal and intent should have already been considered by whatever community is supporting it; there is no need whatsoever to discuss it broadly. It only serves to promote the proposal in an inappropriate way, and verges on being spam.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we need to actively police these kinds of questions, but the best place to make your case for a proposal *is in the definition*. It should be clear what the proposal is about based on the questions that the proposal receives.

Now, the proposer can only add so many questions, so I think it's reasonable to allow for people to communicate what they had in mind in cases where it might not be immediately obvious to some.

I would say we should *try* to allow them, though if unclear and it seems unlikely that the OP is ever going to edit, then they can be closed for other reasons. In this case it seems like the author is just struggling a bit to express the topic - maybe give them some time to work it out. If it fizzles out the system will automatically close the proposal soon enough anyway.